# How do I go about creating the method?

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to create a class in java, to this specification:

[image]

I'm not sure how to create "ratings" since I'm seeing its using some
map function using the input of a string and an integer.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Movie {
    String ID;
    String Name;
    String Description;
    String Genre[];
    String Directors[];
    String Actors[];
    String Language;
    String CountryOfOrigin;
}
```

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> ratings`

Comment: Thank you. Is everything else correct so far?

Comment: Refer my answer below

Comment: Check out [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), it shows an example of declaring private fields with public getters and setters.

Comment: Depending on how closely you need to follow the specification, you should note that the capitalization you're using in the code is different. For example, you have `ID` in the code but the spec calls it `id`. Also language should be an array of String.

Answer (score 1):

Please create  different objects for genre, director, actor and rating. It will be a best practice when you try to add more information to each entity.

Use access modifier "private" to each attribute and implement get,set methods as required.

Use ArrayLists instead of arrays to avoid resizing efforts when required.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Genre {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Genre(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class Director {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Director(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class Actor {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Actor(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class Rating {
    private int value;
    private String name;

    public Actor(int value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Movie {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Genre> generes;
    private List<Director> directors;
    private List<Actor> actors;
    private String language;
    private String countryOfOrigin;

    pulic Movie(int id, String name, String description, String language, String countryOfOrigin){
        this.id = id;
        // set other variables
        this.actors = new ArrayList<Actor>();
        // create other lists
    }

    public void addGenere(Genre genere){
        this.generes.add(genere);
    }
    // implement other add methods to lists
}
```